# adding html tag inside typescript file in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

i am using angular2 so i want to implement html tag  inside the return function in ts file

```
  tooltip: (param: any) => {
        return `<span> ${param.value} </span>`;
      }
```

i have tried to use template literal but that make my span visible.

[image]

is there any idea how can i use the span proper way

Comment: You have to use `DomSanitizer` with the function `bypassSecurityTrustHtml`

Comment: Use innerHTML `<div [innerHTML]="tooltip(param)'"></div>`  Can you share more code as Calling methods in bindings in not recommended as it would be invoked in every change detection cycle Instead use a property and bind it in inner html.

Answer (score 3):

try this code 
[stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-we5hgo)

> ```
> import {Component, NgModule, Pipe, PipeTransform} from '@angular/core'
> import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'
> import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
>
> import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser'
>
> @Pipe({ name: 'safeHtml'})
> export class SafeHtmlPipe implements PipeTransform  {
>   constructor(private sanitized: DomSanitizer) {}
>   transform(value) {
>     console.log(this.sanitized.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value))
>     return this.sanitized.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value);
>   }
> }
>
> @Component({
>   selector: 'my-app',
>   template: `<div [innerHtml]="tooltip('Hello World') | safeHtml">
>     </div>`,
>   styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
> })
> export class AppComponent  {
>   name = 'Angular';
>   tooltip(param: any) {
>         return `<span> ${param} </span>`;
>       }
> }
> ```